# Multiple ArrayList with 10 records using iterator and ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Mutliple Arraylist<> with 10 records. i have used like this for limiting upto 10 results , but how to get the next 10 results and so on.

```
try {
ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput> results = new ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput>();

List<?> eventsToday = (List<?>) filter.filter(calendar.getComponents(Component.VEVENT));
CalanderQueryOutput caldavOutput = new CalanderQueryOutput();

for (Iterator<?> i = eventsToday.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
if(Limit < RsLimit){
    results.add(caldavOutput);  
    Limit++;
    }
      }

 }
```

Comment: sorry not clear, you mean you want multiple arraylists with 10 records in each ?

Comment: yes i want 10 record each in arraylist

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need some other data strcuture to store multiple arraylists, you can use list of list like

```
List<List<CalanderQueryOutput>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<CalanderQueryOutput>>();
List<CalanderQueryOutput> results = new ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput>();
for (Iterator<?> i = eventsToday.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
if(Limit < RsLimit){
    results.add(caldavOutput);  
    Limit++;
    }else{
     resultList.add(results);
     Limit = 0;
     results = new ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput>();
}
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have Modified my code which works for ArrayList  with iterator

```
 int inc = 0;
 int IOF = Integer.parseInt(ItemOffset);
 inc = IOF;
 int IC = Integer.parseInt(ItemCount);
 int TotalLimit = 0;
 int EventLimit = 0;
 for (int l = 0; l < IC; ++l) {
++IOF;
EventLimit = IOF;
 }

 try {
 ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput> results = new ArrayList<CalanderQueryOutput>();
 List<?> eventsToday = (List<?>)filter.filter(calendar.getComponents(Component.VEVENT));
 CalanderQueryOutput caldavOutput = new CalanderQueryOutput();

 for (Iterator<?> i = eventsToday.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
   if (TotalLimit < eventsToday.size()) {
    if (TotalLimit >= inc && TotalLimit <= EventLimit - 1){
       results.add(caldavOutput);
         }
     TotalLimit++;
      }
 }catch (SardineException e){
 }
```